# AndroidStudio Freeze while working on UI

Tags: android, android-studio

In the last couple of days, my AndroidStudio suddenly freezes while working on the UI. It's simply freezes and even if I wait for 10 minutes it won't resume itself and the only thing I can do is to terminate the process through task manager and start the Studio again.

I checked for updated to the AndroidStudio thinking this might help so I did the update and my current version is:

[image]

But even after the update -  it's still happens after about 5 minutes of work on the UI.
I took a screen shout of task manager after the freeze happened and it doesn't seem like it happens due to some overload on the system , here's the screenshot:
[image]

I searched the forum before posting but I didn't find any post that described the same problem as I have.

I continued exploring my problem in order to make it more specific and fount out that it's only freezes when I'm trying to use the extract resource window in order to make my views name by the String.xml instead of direct writing the value to the text field of each view.
This is the extract resource window I'm talking about.

[image]

I hope it will make it easier for you to understand my problem and help me with a solution.
Thank you in advance,
Noam

Comment: Does it happen always editing the same xml file?